# I wish to avoid overrunning the http connections pool

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

I am creating a tool that will run many simultaneous calls to a RESTful API.  I am using the python "Requests" module and the "threading" module.  Once I stack too many simultaneous gets on the system I am getting exceptions like this:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxx.net', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /thing/subthing/ (Caused by : [Errno 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full)

What can I do to either increase the buffer and queue space, or ask the Requests module to wait for an available slot?

(I know I could stuff it in a "try" loop, but that seems clumsy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api.html#request-sessions). If you use the `requests.request` family of methods (get, post, ...), each request will use it's own session with it's own connection pool, therfore not making any use of connection pooling.

If you need to fine-tune the number of connections used within a session, you can do this by changing it's [`HTTPAdapter`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api.html#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter)